# Python Pandas Pivot - Change Aggc columns values to rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"AgentName": ['airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails'],
               "OutputTableName": ['carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx'],
               "LastModified": ['10/13/2018', '10/13/2018', '10/12/2018', '10/12/2018', '10/11/2018', '10/11/2018', '10/10/2018', '10/09/2018', '10/08/2018', '10/07/2018'],
               "Size": [540722, 1995963, 541308, 2179389, 469444, 1519627, 472355, 472622, 1691951, 2012013]
                })
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['AgentName', 'OutputTableName'], values='Size', columns='LastModified', aggfunc=[np.sum, 'count'])

#stacked = pivot.stack(0)

print (pivot.head())
```

I have to sum the size and how many records we have per date.

After doing the pivot Sum and Count appears in column whereas I want in rows like this

[what code I have to write to achieve same kind of output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2CfZ.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you uncomment `stacked = pivot.stack(0)` you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should return what you want if you just uncomment the `stacked = pivot.stack(0)`

If you want the index column to be sorted like the image and have the name `Values` you can do this:

```
# Given
df = pd.DataFrame({"AgentName": ['airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails', 'airlines_all_flightdetails'],
               "OutputTableName": ['carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx', 'carrier=xx'],
               "LastModified": ['10/13/2018', '10/13/2018', '10/12/2018', '10/12/2018', '10/11/2018', '10/11/2018', '10/10/2018', '10/09/2018', '10/08/2018', '10/07/2018'],
               "Size": [540722, 1995963, 541308, 2179389, 469444, 1519627, 472355, 472622, 1691951, 2012013]
                })

# Given
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['AgentName', 'OutputTableName'], values='Size', columns='LastModified', aggfunc=[np.sum, 'count'])

# Moves 'Values' from columns to index
stacked = pivot.stack(0)

# sorts index to relfect image
stacked.sort_index(level = 2, ascending = False, inplace = True)

# renames inner index to 'Values'
stacked.index.rename('Values', level = 2, inplace = True)

# rename inner index values
stacked.rename(index = {
    'sum' : 'Sum of Size',
    'count' : 'Count of OutputFileName'
})
```

Should return the following:

[image: output]